# using msvcrt in python (eclipse editor) not working

Tags: python, eclipse

I have an application where the program must loop continously until a key is pressed.

I tried to use functions from the msvcrt library, but none seems to work. In fact a programm as simple as the one given below doesn't work:

```
import msvcrt
print "opening"
k=msvcrt.getche()
print k
```

On further search I found that [eclipse has a bug and many are facing this problem](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=375172).

Is there a workaround?